# FunctionClauseError when passing map

Tags: elixir

Following function expecting a map

```
 def process_info({k, v}) do
   --- code---
 end
```

And when i call above function with my_map
 which is `%{"tt1034415" => "Suspiria"}` like

```
process_info(my_map)
```

then the following error is raised

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in MOVIEMATCH.process_info/1    

    The following arguments were given to MOVIEMATCH.process_info/1:

        # 1
        %{"tt1034415" => "Suspiria"}

    Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):

        def process_info({k, v})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{k, v}` is a tuple, `%{k => v}` is a map. Your function is expecting a tuple.

You might be tempted to try to fix this by changing the definition of `def_process` to expect a map:

```elixir
def process_info(%{k => v})
```

However, this does not work. The reason is that pattern matching a map in the function arguments is designed to let you select the relevant data out of the map for processing inside the function. For example, the following map:

```elixir
%{"one" => 1, "two" => 2}
```

Can be pattern matched like this:

```elixir
def process_info(%{"one" => one})
```

Then inside your function, the value of `one` is `1`. For this reason you need to know the names of the keys you want to match in advance.

It's difficult to tell in your case without seeing the contents of `--- code ---`, and what happens before you call `process_info/1`, but one method is to convert the map to a tuple:

```elixir
[tuple] = Map.to_list(my_map)
```

Generating the tuple without the map in the first instance would be a better design though.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pattern match against a `Tuple` not a `Map`.

for `Map` you need to do this:

```
def process_info(%{"tt1034415" => value}) do
    # your code
end
```

> Also, notice that you can't use variable to pattern match on map key, you need to be explicit on key